# Where to set up a TableViewController's UIBarButtonItem & cell "segue" programmatically

Tags: ios, segue

I have a TableViewController that can be transitioned to from two other view controllers; one transitions by segue, and the other programmatically.  Everything works well when transitioning via segue, but when the TableViewController appears after a programmatic transition, the UIBarButtonItem is missing and the cell segue doesn't work (it should take the user to a new screen).

I'm guessing that because the UIBarButtonItem and cell segue were setup in the Storyboard, they aren't loaded when the TableViewController is loaded programmatically.  So, I'm assuming that I need to load them manually somewhere.  My question is where the appropriate place to do this is?

Thanks for reading.

**EDIT:**
Here's the code for the transition:

```
OtherTVC *otherTVC=[[OtherTVC alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:otherTVC animated:YES];
```

This is linked to the callout accessory of a map pin.

Comment: What does the code for the programmatic transition look like?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  See above for the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get an instance of the controller as it was created in the storyboard, try giving it an identifier and using `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:` rather than the `alloc/init` route.  If your current controller where the code is running came from the same storyboard, you can get a reference to it through the controller's `storyboard` property in order to make that call.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  To give a controller an identifier, is it the  "Storyboard ID" field in Identity Inspector that needs to be changed?  (And the "Use Storyboard ID" checkbox?)

Comment: Looks like the answer is yes.  It's working perfectly now, thanks!